# Custom Exception including messages

Tags: java

Hello i am trying to create my custom exception and i want to show me the message "Order does not exist" rather then "Not found". I will include the source code:
RetailinIn_APIException.java:

```
public class RetailIn_APIException extends ResponseStatusException {

    public static final HttpStatus ORDER_NOT_FOUND_STATUS = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    public static final String ORDER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "Order does not exist";

    public RetailIn_APIException() {
        super(ORDER_NOT_FOUND_STATUS, ORDER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE);
    }
```

ClientOrderService.java:

```
public Optional<ClientOrder> getOrderById(Long orderId) throws RetailIn_APIException {
        Optional<ClientOrder> retrievedOrder = orderRepository.findById(orderId);
        if (retrievedOrder.isPresent())
            return retrievedOrder;
        else
            throw new RetailIn_APIException();
}
```

ClientOrderController.java:

```
@GetMapping("/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<ClientOrder>> getOrderById(@PathVariable Long orderId) throws RetailIn_APIException {

            Optional<ClientOrder> orderOptional = orderService.getOrderById(orderId);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(orderOptional);

    }
```

If you guys will help me, will it be the right way for future custom exceptions?
Thank you for you time and help.

Comment: doesn't the constructor `ResponseStatusException(HttpStatusCode status, String reason)` provide you the argument `reason` to pass the error message of your choice? If you add a new constructor, `public RetailIn_APIException(String message) { super(ORDER_NOT_FOUND_STATUS, message);  }` it should work

Comment: adding your changes @MarcLeBihan this is the response i get:"{
    "timestamp": "2023-08-23T14:51:22.145+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/orders/8"
}"

Answer (score 0):

Whether the message is shown in Json responses depends on the application property [server.error.include-message](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.error.include-message). Since Spring Boot 2.3, by default, [the message is not shown due to security reasons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content). If you want it to be shown, you can set the property to `always`.